# How to convert ("1,2,3") to ("1","2","3")

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, csv, where-clause

I am trying to get some results from a column that has both string and integer with `varchar` type in Postgre. I tried to use `IN`, but got some errors.

I want to convert

```
select * from asdasd where bla in ("1,2,3")
```

to

```
select * from asdasd where bla in ("1","2","3")
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of task in tedious in many databases, but fortunately Postgres has great strings and array features, which make it quite easy to do what you want.

You could turn the string to an array, and then use `any()`:

```
select *
from asdasd
where bla = any(string_to_array('1,2,3', ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM where bla in (STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3', ','));
```